# Should I file a change of address with the IRS?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I recently finished my tax filing for the year, and I'm expecting a direct deposit refund for both my federal and state taxes.

However, I'll soon be moving to a new address - in about 2 weeks.  I've informed all parties that require foreknowledge of the move, but do I need to inform either the IRS or my state (New York) tax department of my intention to move, even though I'm not expecting a physical check in the mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing to do when moving is to [change your address with the post office](https://moversguide.usps.com/icoa/home/icoa-main-flow.do?execution=e1s1&_flowId=icoa-main-flow). This will forward most mail for a year, and even automatically send change of address notices to many businesses that send mail to you. If you do this, and the IRS needs to send you something over the next year, you'll get it.

The IRS does have a [procedure for changing your address](https://www.irs.gov/help-resources/tools-faqs/faqs-for-individuals/frequently-asked-tax-questions-answers/irs-procedures/address-changes/address-changes), and you would want to do this if you are expecting something from the IRS and are unable to do a change of address with the post office for some reason. But if you do forward your mail and you aren't expecting a refund check, I don't think it is necessary. The IRS will get your new address when you file your return next year.